# HMAC-SHA-256 in PHP

Tags: php, hmac

I have to build an authorization hash from this string:

```
kki98hkl-u5d0-w96i-62dp-xpmr6xlvfnjz:20151110171858:b2c13532-3416-47d9-8592-a541c208f755:hKSeRD98BHngrNa51Q2IgAXtoZ8oYebgY4vQHEYjlmzN9KSbAVTRvQkUPsjOGu4F
```

This secret is used for a HMAC hash function:

```
LRH9CAkNs-zoU3hxHbrtY0CUUcmqzibPeN7x6-vwNWQ=
```

The authorization hash I have to generate is this:

```
P-WgZ8CqV51aI-3TncZj5CpSZh98PjZTYxrvxkmQYmI=
```

There are some things to take care of:

1. The signature have to be built with HMAC-SHA-256 as specified in [RFC 2104](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2104).
2. The signature have to be encoded with Base64 URL-compatible as specified in [RFC 4648 Section 5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648) (Safe alphabet).

There is also some pseudo-code given for the generation:

```
Signatur(Request) = new String(encodeBase64URLCompatible(HMAC-SHA-256(getBytes(Z, "UTF-8"), decodeBase64URLCompatible(getBytes(S, "UTF-8")))), "UTF-8")
```

I tried various things in PHP but have not found the correct algorithm yet. This is the code I have now:

```
if(!function_exists('base64url_encode')){
    function base64url_encode($data) {
        $data = str_replace(array('+', '/'), array('-', '_'), base64_encode($data));
        return $data;
    }
}

$str = "kki98hkl-u5d0-w96i-62dp-xpmr6xlvfnjz:20151110171858:b2c13532-3416-47d9-8592-a541c208f755:hKSeRD98BHngrNa51Q2IgAXtoZ8oYebgY4vQHEYjlmzN9KSbAVTRvQkUPsjOGu4F";
$sec = "LRH9CAkNs-zoU3hxHbrtY0CUUcmqzibPeN7x6-vwNWQ=";
$signature = mhash(MHASH_SHA256, $str, $sec);
$signature = base64url_encode($signature);

if($signature != "P-WgZ8CqV51aI-3TncZj5CpSZh98PjZTYxrvxkmQYmI=")
    echo "wrong: $signature";
else
    echo "correct";
```

It gives this signature:

```
K9lw3V-k5gOedmVwmO5vC7cOn82JSEXsNguozCAOU2c=
```

As you can see, the length of 44 characters is correct. Please help me with finding the mistake, this simple problem takes me hours yet and there is no solution.

Comment: After reading your question twice I still don't know what your issue/question is.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois: I need a HMAC hash from a string to sign and a secret. If I try to generate it with PHP, it fails / gives the wrong hash. I think the RFC specifications are not fulfilled.

Comment: I think it's pretty much because of `base64url_encode`. If you need it to be urlencoded for whatever reason, use `urlencode` and then `urldecode` it on the server before verifying.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's a couple of things to notice:

1. Your key is base64-encoded. You have to decode it before you could use it with php functions. That's the most important thing you have missed.
2. Mhash is obsoleted by [Hash](http://php.net/hash) extension.
3. You want output to be encoded in a custom fashion, so it follows that you need raw output from hmac function (php, by default, will hex-encode it).

So, using hash extension this becomes:

```
$key = "LRH9CAkNs-zoU3hxHbrtY0CUUcmqzibPeN7x6-vwNWQ=";
$str = "kki98hkl-u5d0-w96i-62dp-xpmr6xlvfnjz:20151110171858:b2c13532-3416-47d9-8592-a541c208f755:hKSeRD98BHngrNa51Q2IgAXtoZ8oYebgY4vQHEYjlmzN9KSbAVTRvQkUPsjOGu4F";

function encode($data) {
    return str_replace(['+', '/'], ['-', '_'], base64_encode($data));
}

function decode($data) {
    return base64_decode(str_replace(['-', '_'], ['+', '/'], $data));
}

$binaryKey = decode($key);

var_dump(encode(hash_hmac("sha256", $str, $binaryKey, true)));
```

Outputs:

```
string(44) "P-WgZ8CqV51aI-3TncZj5CpSZh98PjZTYxrvxkmQYmI="
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that is exactly the result I needed! The problem just was the `true` in `hash_hmac` and the base64 decode of the key, which needs base64 URL also.

Comment: will hash_hmac will always generate unique string...?

Comment: No, it's output is based on input string and the key. Give it the same key and string, and it will generate the same output.

Answer (score 7):

Simply use **hash_hmac()** function available in PHP.

Example :

```
hash_hmac('sha256', $string, $secret);
```

Doc here : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.hash-hmac.php

Comment: The output is `d6285e20328c93ef83aa34b2318e3d14c193fc517e81f4cf13e8120a7b995899`, which is not the desired answer.